# How to connect to an xml/soap web service via SSL with mutual auth?

Tags: ruby, web-services, savon, net-http, mutual-authentication

I'm trying to consume a web service with a certificate, sending a XML/SOAP, via SSL with mutual authentication. I've tried `savon` and `net/http`, but I'm stopped with the same error:

> SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey: key values mismatch (HTTPI::SSLError)

**net/http**:

```
uri = URI.parse('https://homologacao.sefaz.mt.gov.br/nfews/v2/services/NfeStatusServico2?wsdl')
pem = File.read("cert/cert.pem")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(pem)
http.key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(pem)
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER

http.start
```

**savon**:

```
WSDL_URL = 'https://homologacao.sefaz.mt.gov.br/nfews/v2/services/NfeStatusServico2?wsdl'

client = Savon.client(
   wsdl: WSDL_URL,
   ssl_version: :SSLv3,
   ssl_verify_mode: :peer,
   ssl_cert_file: 'cert/cert.pem',
   ssl_cert_key_file: 'cert/private_key.pem',
 # ssl_cert_key_password: '123456789',
   env_namespace: :soap, 
   namespace_identifier: nil
)

response = client.call(:nfeStatusServicoNF2, message: "test")
```

Is there a solution?  Thanks!

Comment: Savon uses HTTPI for the http communication. HTTPI picks one of the installed clients on your system. You should switch on logging to see which client it uses OR you can force it to use net/http. If I remember correctly then net/http is not the preferred client. I personally use HTTPClient for all my http stuff.

Comment: Have you tried http.rb?

Comment: Certificates are tied to FQDN. You are trying to connect to `homologacao.sefaz.mt.gov.br`; does your `cert.pem` generated to certify requests to this particular domain?

Comment: did you find a solution with Savon calling HTTPS SOAP webservices?